# Embedding PHP code in a CSS file

Tags: php, css

Can we embed php code in a css file. I need to add conditions to css properties.

styles.css

```
<?php
 if($suserid == 2) 
 { ?>
   .proverb { border:0px solid blue; margin-left:34px; width:250px !important; margin-top:6px; } <?php
 }
 else
 { ?>
   .proverb { border:0px solid blue; margin-left:0px; } <?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: create a file named "style.css.php" and write your conditional css in that file.

Comment: Technically CSS can be embedded in a PHP file. And you just need to set the Content-type of the document to `text/css`.

Comment: Do the following one: 1. `if ($suserid == 2) echo "<div class='proverb2'>user</div>";` 2. css: `.proverb2 { ...`

Comment: yes if your php configuration can interpret it

Comment: No, you cannot use PHP in external CSS files. However, you can use it in internal CSS (when there's a `<style> ... </style>` tag in your HTML `<head>`).

Comment: You should not depend on user-ids (or the like) in your CSS. Good practice would be adding a special class, and applying this to the elements *in the HTML*. Ie. `<div class="proverb special-case"></div>` with a corresponding `.proverb.special-case` in your CSS. --- CSS should be static, as **browsers cache it**. If something changes dynamically in your CSS, your browser will ignore it.

Comment: I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27742082/1080564) expanding with an alternate approach, that is better practice.

Answer (score 7):

**Your request is bad practice. Do not proceed.**

While it is [technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27741936/1080564) to do this, you should look into alternatives. **Do not dynamically generate CSS files**. They will be cached by your browsers, and dynamic changes will not be propagated.

Instead, make special-case classes that you can add to the HTML. Your CSS would become:

```
.proverb {
  border: 0px solid blue;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.proverb.user-2 {
  margin-left: 34px;
  width: 250px !important;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

In your HTML-generating code you can have:

```
<div class="proverb <?php if($suserid == 2) echo "user-2"; ?>"></div>
```

This will add the `user-2` class *if the user id is 2*, and gives the same result as what you wanted in your example.

Answer (score 3):

A file is considered PHP by the handlers your webserver attaches to a file type or file extension. If a file is considered PHP, the contents will be executed as PHP code.
Assuming you're using apache, you can add the php handler to CSS files by adding the following in your VirtualHost file or in your .htaccess file:

`<Directory "/path/to/your/css/dir">
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
</Directory>`

The only downside is this changes the output mime-type to text/html of all css files in the given directory. Therefore you have to override the mime-type so browsers know you're sending css in stead of html. Trough PHP you can use: `<?php header('Content-type: text/css'); ?>` on the first line of every css file.

Keep in mind changing the handler to php for css files does put more stress on your server, since every file has to be parsed before it can be sent to the output buffer. Therefore it's easier and better to just add an extra class to your html output and adjust your css accordingly, like @Rizier123 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.

First you have to tell your web server to serve `*.css` files through the PHP ISAPI module, then you can embed the code.

But this is not a good practice and I'd advise not to do so. There are better solutions, like [SASS and LESS](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/).